# Sites to be used for running training Selenium tests against

Tags: testing, selenium, automated-tests

I want to teach myself automated testing, specifically web sites automated testing using various tools like Selenium, Watir, etc. The problem is that many real sites contain captchas and other means that make running tests harder against them.

**Could you please recommend some complex sites with various controls that are best used for running my training tests against?**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will Recommend you this link
[Automation Practise](http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: Thank you very much, Rupesh! This is very interesting and useful site indeed. It would be great to also find one there some complex user scenarios could be automated. Such tests might not only be more challenging but their code is also looks better while demonstrated to recruiters.